# Export Address Inspector Address Points into its own layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, address

I am a new ArcMap user.

I have the ArcMap Base Map, some county parcel data layers and found two important addresses from the data using the 'Address Inspector' as shown in the pictures and placed a point.

Is there a way to turn these points into its own separate layer? In the layer pallet, all I have is the Base Map, and Parcel Data layers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this with graphics created from the Address Inspector.  In fact, I haven't tried this ever.  But what you're trying to do is create features from graphics.  Fortunately, this is possible when you're viewing graphics in the Data View and not Layout View.[image]

If you right click on the data frame in the table of contents (by default, this is called "Layers" and select "Convert Graphics to Features".

[image]

Follow the prompts in the dialog. You can save to a shapefile or geodatabase and add that to your table of contents.

[image]

Note, this tool is also available on the Drawing toolbar.
[image]

The resulting feature class will have a "Name" field which should contain your addresses.

Comment: This worked perfect and even worked with addresses. Thanks!